# How to change the starting value of the guide in a ggplot choropleth?

Tags: r, ggplot2, choropleth, rescale

i just need a minor tweak. I am drawing a choropleth with `ggplot`. Everything works fine, except one ecstatically misleading aspect: as you can see in the figure here

[image: choropleth]

ggplot picks `0` as a starting value for the shading of the provinces, while the vector of values lies between `0.331` and `0.591`. I believe a starting value of, say, `300`, would enhance the differences between the different provinces.

This is my code:

```
  ggplot(final.plot.orph, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = id, fill = CMPI)) +
  geom_polygon() + 
  coord_equal() +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Blues", direction = 1) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA, colour = "#cccccc"))  + 
  with(province_orph, annotate(geom = "text", x = lab_long, y = lab_lat, label = label, size = 2.5))
```

I guess it has something to do with the `scale_fill_distiller`. After looking at the documentation, I tried to include

```
rescale(to = c(0.300, 0.600), from = c(0, 1))
```

as an argument of the `scale_fill_distiller` line but I get an error message that says one argument (i.e. `x`) is missing. I also tried using `.` as `x`, but got the following error message

```
Error in rescale(., to = c(0.3, 0.6), from = c(0, 1)) : 
  object '.' not found
```

Data available [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PhJoIU8IK4oyOW_xzsp9tQMEmIcd5jc0/view?usp=sharing), in case of need.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand why the values are 3 orders of magnitude lower then your desired starting values, but you can set scale limits bij doing for example: `scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Blues", direction = 1, limits = c(300, NA))`, wherein the `NA` indicates that the natural upper limit should be taken.

Comment: thanks @teunbrand that works well! not sure why they are lower, I suspect it might be from a previous choropleth, though I did not change and stored any setting there. One small edit, your code works by setting the lower limit to `0.300`, not `300`, to keep with the values of each province. Cheers!